# Can use session to set the language?

Tags: php, forms, session, post, translate

Would like to know whether I can use session method for language translate? I tested the code and it's working fine.

This is the Form button

```
<form method="post">
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['english'])){
        echo "<button type='submit' name='Chinese'>Chinese</button>";
    }else{
    echo "<button type='submit' name='english'>English</button>";
    }   
?>  
</form>
```

PHP Session to translate

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['english'])){
        $_SESSION['english'] = $_POST['english'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['chinese'])){
        unset($_SESSION['english']);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['english'])){
        echo "English";
    }else{
    echo "Chinese";
}
?>
```

My code is working fine but i just want to confirm is that OK to use session for translate the language

Comment: it means your site will be indexed by a search engine in the default language only

Comment: Yes, When someone click on the translate button than the language will change

Comment: But search engines don't click buttons. Plus, if I wanted to share the URL to one of your pages with someone, they might not actually see the same content I did (which could be important, if I was trying to refer to something specific in that particular language version.) The language indicator belongs into the URL. Not into a session, not into a cookie.

Comment: Ooow OK. It's a good point and thank you for the info. I will do the url pass than